# Which Wireless communication system is the best for streaming video?

Tags: video, bluetooth, wireless

I wanted to implement Classic Bluetooth 4.0 to stream the video in a car. 2Mbps the speed of BT, I thought this would be enough to stream a video but then I read that Bluetooth is not the right choice to stream the video. So I was searching in the internet why is this not a good choice, but didn't find much about it. Is it because BT is working on frequency hopping?

If BT is not a good choice then Which can I implement to stream the video? Will the RF be a good choice or I have to implement the Wi-Fi? I was also concern about the Power consumption, Wi-Fi will consume more power, So it is possible to use some other wireless connections like Rf, ANT, ZigBee etc...

Looking for some suggestions :)

Comment: what is the minimum required throughput for application data?

Comment: I want to transmit SD video for a small screen so I was thinking of throughput of like 1-2 Mbps, So for this which communication method would be the best choice?

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted if it answers your question. So that it moves to answered questions list

Answer (score 0):

I had suggest Wi-Fi should be relatively reliable solution for streaming application like yours. You may want to check Wi-Fi direct, if your application is more of a Peer-to-Peer communication.

Answer (score 0):

Wi-fi would be a good choice with better bandwidth!!
If you are also concern about the Power consumption, Wi-Fi will consume more power, So it is possible to use some other wireless connections like Rf, ANT, ZigBee etc